# creating parameter in php to execute javascript function produces error

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

I create a link executing javascript if clicked. (And a div popup is displayed containing the content of $test)

The php code looks like:

```
echo "<a ID=\"it_$idnr\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"javascript:it_popup('it_$idnr','$test');\">"
```

The problem is that in some cases this code produces an error:
Syntax error: unterminated string literal

It seams to that it happens only if the $test contains special chars like new line or quotation marks.

How can I prevent this perfectly? 
A simple search and replace is not a solution, because it should not change the result.

Comment: try using htmlspecialchars($test)

Comment: htmlspecialchars() seems not to be enough the error still occurs.

Comment: with htmlspecialchars() the error is not reproducable with quotation marks, but still with newline chars

Comment: It's the %0A in $text which causes the error, but I'm not able to str_replace it. Strange!

Comment: Got it to work with preg_replace("/\r|\n/s", "<br/>", $test)

Answer (score 0):

You can json_encode it to make it js safe and html encode it to make it html safe

```
echo "<a ID=\"it_$idnr\" class=\"tooltip\" href=\"javascript:it_popup('it_$idnr',".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test)).");\">"
```

Comment: @Klaus What is `$test` in this case?

Comment: $test can contain a lot of text, entered by a person. It could contain every character.

Comment: The problem is that $text sometimes contains %0A and this produces the error.

Comment: @Klaus I see whats going on, in the href attribute the %0a is getting decoded and thus creating a line break. Can you use the onclick attribute instead of the href?

Comment: I got it to work with preg_replace("/\r|\n/s", "<br/>",$test)